# flash builder run as administrator different preferences

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I have to run Flash Builder as administrator to install an xml formatter that I want to use. I found that it has removed all my preferences like hot keys that I setup and my perspectives etc.

If I switch back to just running not as administrator I get them back but now I don't have the xml formatter anymore.

Any idea how I can have both? Without having to always run as administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a windows feature:
when you run some executables from some user, all additional/temporary information are storing in special folder

`C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\AppData`

so when you did installation you did it into C:\Users\Administrator\AppData, but if you run from another user, there are no C:\Users\User\AppData application files in this folder, thats why it have such behavior.

Let me know the xml formatter you installed and maybe I could advice you.
Or try find something similar in eclipse software repositories.

Regards
Eugene